# How to get the orders of subviews into an array?

Tags: ios, uiview, nsarray

I have many subviews layout randomly in another supperView.

I want to put them all to an array with order base on their location from left to right, up to down:

ex:

view1 - view2 - view3

view4 - view5 - view6

array = {view1, view2, view3, view4, view5, view6}

How can I always get the right order(array indexes) when array = superView.subviews ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subviews` will always return them in order from back to front in the view hierarchy.

> You can use this property to retrieve the subviews associated with
>   your custom view hierarchies. The order of the subviews in the array
>   reflects their visible order on the screen, with the view at index 0
>   being the back-most view. ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17))

You will have to keep track of them on your own if this is not the order that reflects what you are aiming for. You will likely have to manually sort them based on the `origin` property`, which is a struct a few levels down.